# Python - Save all data with a key missing or present

Tags: python

I am retrieving data via api and I want to save all data regardless if a key is missing or not.

Here is my code which saves the data only when the key is present.

```
#get all of the initial users
initialUsers = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

data = initialUsers.json()



userData = data['data']


# write to a txt file
with open('Users.txt', 'x', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for i in userData:
        if i.get('presence_id') is not None:
            sheet=(i['username']+" ",i['first_name']+" ", i['last_name']+" ", i['presence_id'])
            f.write(str(sheet)+"\n")
```

**presence_id** is the key that is sometimes present.

How can I modify this to save all the data regardless if they key is present or not?

Comment: You can use `get` to return a default value if it's not present.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to save some "default data" if the data is not found:

```py
# ...
with open('Users.txt', 'x', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for i in userData:
        default_data = {"username":"", "first_name":"", "last_name":""}
        output = i.get('presence_id', default_data) # this will never be None. Equals default_data if "presence_id" is not found.
        sheet=(output['username']+" ",output['first_name']+" ", output['last_name']+" ", output['presence_id'])
        f.write(str(sheet)+"\n")
```

Comment: Let's say if presence_id key does not exist then I want to put in a empty value for example.

Comment: Edited to change my answer :)

Comment: I set all the `username`, `first_name`, etc. variables to empty strings in the `default_data` dict here. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I done

I used .setdefault

```
for i in userData:
            i.setdefault('presence_id', "No ext")
            sheet=(i['username']+" ",i['first_name']+" ", i['last_name']+" ", i['presence_id'])
            f.write(str(sheet)+"\n")
```